# How do I play the captured video?

Tags: javascript, video, tabs, mediastream

So I tried to capture the video using the chrome.tabCapture.capture API, but I can't play it back.

I have tested it on audio, which works perfectly fine, but video doesn't work

```
var newVideo = document.createElement('video')

chrome.tabCapture.capture({video: true}, stream => {
   newVideo.srcObject = stream;
   newVideo.play();
}
```